# passing parameter to another component using Link in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface

I know if I need to call another `component` then we need to pass like `<A x={y}/>` and we can access `props.x` inside `A`.

But here I need to call `EditCertificate` so I need to pass `id` to `EditCertificate`. but I am using `Link` here. I am not able to pass the `id`. when I am accesssing it, it is coming `undefined`.

```
<Link to={`/${props.certificate.id}/edit` }  >Edit</Link>
```

and I am calling this page like below.

```
<Route path ="/:id/edit" component={EditCertificate} ></Route>
```

how can I access `:id` inside the `EditCertificate` .when I am accessing it is giving `undefined`. do I need to pass some other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `EditCertificate` is rendered directly by the route:

```
<Route path ="/:id/edit" component={EditCertificate} />
```

the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) are passed to `EditCertificate`. You just need to access them from props.

```
const { id } = props.match.params;
```

if `EditCertificate` is a class component, then obviously access from `this.props`.

```
const { id } = this.props.match.params;
```

Answer (score 1):

since you're using react-router you can simply import `useParams` hook and get the id in you `EditCertificate` component

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'; 


const { id } = useParams(); // add inside your component body
```

Comment: thanks @Rogelio. actually is is giving error. do I need to pass anythink in Link to access it as param?      Error:::-Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.

    46 |
  > 47 |  const { id } = useParams();

Comment: @NiharikaS no need to pass anything. your component just need to be a child of `Route` <Route path=""><YourComponent/></Route>

Comment: @NiharikaS for reference you can check https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams